# Docker machine not working in windows7 with VPN

Tags: docker-machine

After connecting to VPN I am facing issue with docker-machine create on windows 7. This is the error coming:

This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not
reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as
the Docker daemon port (usually :2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
Checking connection to Docker...
Error creating machine: Error checking the host: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168
.99.101:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.101:2376: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.

This issue is coming when connecting to vpn. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Sanjiv